# Need to toggle window resizeTo and show image

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to toggle window resizeTo while also showing an image on the initial resize. My window resize function is this...

```
function resizeWin()
    {
        window.resizeTo(1200,848);
        window.focus();                                  
    }
```

But this function only goes one way. I need it to resize back to the initial size. I also need to be able to show an image on the initial resize in the are that it expands, but I am sure I can manage that once I am able to get the resizeTo function to toggle. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only way to revert the window size back to its original size would be to save its width and height at the time you resize it.  Then whenever you do revert, just do another `resizeTo()` to those parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out another way that I will work with for now. I just added another button to resize back to the original window size.

```
function downSize()
    {
        window.resizeTo(465,748);
        window.focus();
    }
```